# Correct word for a 5-part piece of art?

Tags: single-word-requests

As I am wanting to buy one of these, I'd like to know the actual name of it.

[image]

The name for a 3-part art piece seems to be "triptych" (translated via google from "triptychon").

Through some googleing I found "pentaptych" which doesn't seem to be correct as "pentateuch" is always suggested, but that seems to be specifically for the 5 books of Moses.

**So the question remains: What is the right name for pieces of art that consist of 5 parts?**

Comment: I see that the tag might be wrong as the question doesn't fulfill the requirements, but I couldn't find a better fitting tag. If you think another tag fits better, feel free to update. Or might the question be a better fit for another SE?

Comment: It's just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right word is indeed ***pentaptych***.

The *ptych* part is directly from the Greek πτυχή=fold — usually these things fold on hinges. *Penta-* is the combining form for "five" in Greek.

There are a number of similar words: diptych (two parts); triptych; tetraptych; pentaptych; hexaptych; heptaptych, and so on. The hypernym is *polyptych,* (*poly*=many).

OED does include *pentaptych,* but marks it as "rare", so it's not really surprising that Google wants to search for Pentateuch instead.

OED also says that the pronunciation is "pentaptic", but I've never heard anything but /-tʃ/ for any of these words, and "pentaptitch" doesn't really show that the "pt" belong together from the Greek *πτ.* I would prefer a pronunciation of /ˈpɛntəˌtɪtʃ/ "pentatitch" (treating pt- as it is in *pterasaur*).

Comment: Regarding pronunciation. For diptych and triptych, dictionaries (e.g. Merriam-Webster) have a syllable break between the /p/ and /t/, and the final sound is /k/ (which is the usual sound in words from ancient Greek with chi/"ch"). "pentaptych" is so seldom spoken it can hardly be considered to have a usual pronunciation other than following these examples.

Comment: In *diptych* and *triptych,* the syllable immediately preceding *-pt-* is stressed. In *pentaptych,* it's not. That can change things.

Comment: Perhaps [pɛn'tæptɪk] for *pentaptych* is credible. English stress often doesn't respect morpheme boundaries: cf ['hɛli,kɒptə] for *helicopter* and [pɛn'tægənəl] for *pentagonal*. Admittedly [ptɪk] is only one syllable, unlike "gonal", but perhaps  it is so heavy that it's more natural to stress the previous vowel than the vowel before that. Cf [sɪ'næptɪk] for *synaptic*.

Comment: The -pt- in *synaptic* is not the same as in *pentaptych,* because that's *synap-* from *synapsis* and *-tic.* Stressing the middle syllable in *pentaptych* grossly distorts the word, I feel (*helicopter* notwithstanding).

Comment: Do you mean you’ve only ever heard _triptych_ with a final /tʃ/? That’s very surprising to me – I don’t recall **ever** hearing it pronounced as anything other than /ˈtrɪptɪk/. I’ve never come across _pentaptych_ before, but it’s immediately understandable, and I would instinctively pronounce it /ˈpɛntəpˌtɪk/. I don’t think I’d immediately understand /ˈpɛntəˌtɪtʃ/ if I heard it spoken.

Answer (score 1):

I think **Polyptych** is the more general word … 
Looking from there you can find names for some specific number of pieces:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyptych

**Pentaptych** is the one with five panels or pieces, it seems…